# hadoop complains about attempting to overwrite nonempty destination directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm following Rasesh Mori's [instructions to install Hadoop on a multinode cluster](https://raseshmori.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/install-hadoop-nextgen-yarn-multi-node-cluster/), and have gotten to the point where jps shows the various nodes are up and running. I can copy files into hdfs; I did so with

`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs dfs -put ~/in /in`

and then tried to run the wordcount example program on it with

`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar wordcount /in /out`

but I get the error

`15/06/16 00:59:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1434414924941_0004_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Rename cannot overwrite non empty destination directory /home/hduser/hadoop-2.6.0/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1434414924941_0004/filecache/10
java.io.IOException: Rename cannot overwrite non empty destination directory /home/hduser/hadoop-2.6.0/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1434414924941_0004/filecache/10
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.renameInternal(AbstractFileSystem.java:716)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFs.renameInternal(FilterFs.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.rename(AbstractFileSystem.java:659)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.rename(FileContext.java:909)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Hadoop 2.6.0. It's been marked as fixed but it still happens occasionally (see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-2624).

Clearing out the appcache directory and restarting the YARN daemons should most likely fix this.

Comment: That's useful to know, so I accepted it. It turns out I was actually using an NFS mounted directory for hadoop.tmp.dir. That seems to have caused the problem...

Comment: Came here looking at same issue.  As information for others, this issue apparently also creeped into Hadoop 2.7.0.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-3832

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with the /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hue/filecache/ directory.
I've done sudo rm -rf /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hue/filecache/* and it solved it.